# attach event in loop, javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, event-handling, return

I know this is a "classic" and I already tried to read different explanatory articles on this subject, but I still manage to do it wrong somehow. I am talking about adding event handlers and functions in a javascript loop.

Here is my code with problems (it's a suggest-box / auto complete)

```
function autoCompleteCB(results) {
document.getElementById('autocom').innerHTML = '';
if (results.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'block';
    var divholders = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        divholders[i] = document.createElement('div');
        divholders[i].style.width = '350px';
        var divrestext = document.createElement('div');
        divrestext.className = 'autocom0';
        divrestext.innerHTML = results[i][0];
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestext);
        var divrestype = document.createElement('div');
        divrestype.className = 'autocom1' + results[i][1];
        divrestype.innerHTML = results[i][1];
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestype);
        divholders[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', (function(i) { return function() { divholders[i].style.backgroundColor='#266699'; }; })(i));
        divholders[i].attachEvent('onmouseout', (function (i) { return function() { divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5'; }; })(i));
        document.getElementById('autocom').appendChild(divholders[i]);
    }
}
}
```

It is (of course) the attachevent lines that do not work. This part of javascript is so weird/tricky :) Can a kind expert help me fix those two lines?

---

This is a half-way fix (I think(:

```
function bindEvent(element, type, listener) {
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + type, listener);
}
}
function autoCompleteCB(results) {
document.getElementById('autocom').innerHTML = '';
if (results.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'block';
    var divholders = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        divholders[i] = document.createElement('div');
        divholders[i].style.width = '350px';
        var divrestext = document.createElement('div');
        divrestext.className = 'autocom0';
        divrestext.innerHTML = results[i][0];
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestext);
        var divrestype = document.createElement('div');
        divrestype.className = 'autocom1' + results[i][1];
        divrestype.innerHTML = results[i][1];
        // BIND THE EVENTS
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestype);
        document.getElementById('autocom').appendChild(divholders[i]);
    }
}
}
```

It looks like this now, but still no "action"

```
function autoComplete() {
var ss = document.getElementById('txbkeyword').value;
if (ss.length > 0) { CSearch.SearchAutoComplete(ss, 3, autoCompleteCB); }
else { document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'none'; }

}
function bindEvent(element, type, listener) {
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + type, listener);
}
}
function autoCompleteCB(results) {
document.getElementById('autocom').innerHTML = '';
if (results.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('autocom').style.display = 'block';
    var divholders = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        divholders[i] = document.createElement('div');
        divholders[i].style.width = '350px';
        var divrestext = document.createElement('div');
        divrestext.className = 'autocom0';
        divrestext.innerHTML = results[i][0];
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestext);
        var divrestype = document.createElement('div');
        divrestype.className = 'autocom1' + results[i][1];
        divrestype.innerHTML = results[i][1];
        (function (i) {
            bindEvent(divholders[i], 'mouseover', function () {
                divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#266699';
            });
            bindEvent(divholders[i], 'mouseout', function () {
                divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
            });
        })(i);
        divholders[i].appendChild(divrestype);
        document.getElementById('autocom').appendChild(divholders[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *It is (of course) the attachevent lines that do not work.* It what sense do they not work?

Comment: they don't change color onmouseover

Comment: why are you passing the index `i` instead of `this`? does the function has an access to `divholders`?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, although there might be more elegant ways... have you debugged your event handlers and checked which value `i` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is because [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343.aspx) is IE-specific. You'll have to use [`attachEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) in many other browsers.

And, to use the "proper" method for the current browser, you'll need to feature-detect them ([snippet from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)):

```
if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener('click', modifyText, false);
} else if (el.attachEvent){
  el.attachEvent('onclick', modifyText);
}
```

You can also create a function to aid in this:

```
function bindEvent(element, type, listener) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, listener);
    }
}
```

Then, in place of these 2 lines:

```
divholders[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', (function(i) { return function() { divholders[i].style.backgroundColor='#266699'; }; })(i));
divholders[i].attachEvent('onmouseout', (function (i) { return function() { divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5'; }; })(i));
```

...use the function to bind your handlers (skipping the `on` in the event type argument):

```
(function (i) {
    bindEvent(divholders[i], 'mouseover', function () {
        divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#266699';
    });
    bindEvent(divholders[i], 'mouseout', function () {
        divholders[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
    });
})(i);
```

---

You could also just enclose the `<div>`:

```
(function (div, i) {
    bindEvent(div, 'mouseover', function () {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#266699';
    });
    bindEvent(div, 'mouseout', function () {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
    });
})(divholders[i], i);
```

Comment: Hi, I totally see your point and your cross browser attach-event function, but I am not sure how to use / where to put one of the last two snippets... inside my loop? Can you help a little more :) I'll put the halfway solution in an edit in my question

Comment: @Jesper Apologies. The snippets should fit in-place of the 2 `divholders[i].attachEvent(...);` calls (or right where you have `// BIND THE EVENTS` in your edit).

Comment: Thanks, I sort of figured that out :) but they still do not change color. pasted the latest rewrite

Comment: It works just fine. I found out that because the inner divs had float:left it would not change color since it renders as 0px height. So adding divholders[i].style.overflow = 'hidden'; made everything work. Weird problem :) Thanks a lot for all the help

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
divholders[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', this.style.backgroundColor='#266699');
```

Comment: No, it's not that easy, because the i is in another scope. It has to look "almost" as my code, but with some modifications... In your example, 'this' is undefined

Comment: You probably forgot `function(){...}` around `this.style....` but even then it would not work. IE does not set `this` to the element the event handler is attached to (it would work with `divholders[i].onmouseover = function(){...}` though).

Comment: Apologies; Wrote that reply in a hurry; Why not set var obj = divholders[i]; and then do 
obj.attachEvent('onmouseover', obj.style.backgroundColor='#266699');

Comment: It's still not correct. `obj.style.backgroundColor='#266699'` will be executed immediately and its *result* will be set as event handler. You will probably still have the closure problem.